# data-bind="attr:{for:id()+'check'}" do not work for 2.3 android but work for 4.0+ android

Tags: android, html, cordova, checkbox, knockout.js

I am using phonegap, html 5,knockout  to develop
Below code do not work for 2.3 android but work for 4.0+ android

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsChecked,attr:{Id:id()+'check'}" class="checkBoxInput" />
                <label data-bind="attr:{for:id()+'check'}"></label>
```

May be a script error but none of the knockout data load after that.

Where as code below (hard-coded without ko) works

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" class="checkBoxInput" />
                <label for="test"></label>
```

Comment: You tried putting the for in single quotes? 'for':id()

Comment: Great its working... thanks  Edward van Raak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your attention [Edward van Raak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2095855/edward-van-raak)

just small change, single quotes? 'for':id() and it work

```
<label data-bind="attr:{'for':id()+'check'}"></label>
```